# Size canvas to adjacent label's text height

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

For a WPF interface, I'm building user controls that display an icon next to a label. I'm building the icon in a Canvas element, and sticking it in a DockPanel next to a Label. I'm bundling this into a UserControl so that the entire control can bind to a single value and redraw the icon and update the text when it changes (think battery meter).

**I'm having trouble scaling the icon's canvas to approximately the same height as the label text and positioning it roughly on the label's baseline.** Is there an easy way to do this? What about if I allow the font to be changed through a property, can I inspect the layout measurements and scale/position the icon's canvas accordingly?

For reference, here is the XAML for a battery meter, and images of both a clock and the battery meter. Note the battery meter is kind of close to what I want (on the baseline, but not quite the height of the text), but the clock is too large.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.Battery"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Controls"
         x:Name="Root"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="900">
<DockPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Root}" LastChildFill="True" Height="200" Width="900">
    <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="200" Height="200" Background="Transparent">
        <Rectangle Width="180" Height="100" StrokeThickness="20" Canvas.Top="50" Stroke="White" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="{Binding Percent}"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Width="40" Height="50" StrokeThickness="20" Canvas.Top="75" Canvas.Right="0" Stroke="White" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
    </Canvas>

    <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Percent, Converter={controls:PercentConverter}}" Foreground="White" />
    </Viewbox>
</DockPanel>
```

[image: Canvas/Label DockPanel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use exact pixel values in your xaml, instead you should bind those values and use converters to set the proper values. (At least this is what I would do...)

So name your TextBlock:

```
<Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textPart" Text="{Binding Percent, Converter={controls:PercentConverter}}" Foreground="White" />
</Viewbox>
```

After that you can bind to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` property of that.

For example:

```
<Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
        Width="200" 
        Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=textPart}" 
        Background="Transparent">
...
```

And to further improve the look you should introduce converters, which would allow you to set for example the width to a given percent of the height, or anything you would like.

Also, you can introduce a [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx) to your canvas, which will - most likely - reduce the need for converters, as you can design your 'pictures' in one size, and only modify the ScaleTansform to make it the right size.

Answer (score 2):

Child elements of a Canvas are never resized, they are just positioned at their designated coordinates. So changing the size of canvas will not affect it's children. Also, child elements of a Canvas are always given the full size that they desire. So in your case i think it's best to use Grid element instead.
Something like that:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.Battery"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Controls"
     x:Name="Root"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="900">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Root}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             Stretch="Uniform"
             StretchDirection="Both">
        <Grid Margin="10 60 10 40">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                       Width="180"
                       Height="100"
                       RadiusX="5"
                       RadiusY="5"
                       Stroke="White"
                       StrokeThickness="20">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="White" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="{Binding Percent}" Color="White" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="1"
                       Width="40"
                       Height="50"
                       Margin="-20 0 0 0"
                       RadiusX="5"
                       RadiusY="5"
                       Stroke="White"
                       StrokeThickness="20" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Percent, Converter={controls:PercentConverter}}" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I could get to a solution. I moved the TextBlock inside the canvas and wrapped with a ViewBox to scale the whole lot, and a ViewBox around the TextBlock to scale that to match the canvas height. I also changed the canvas height to 100 (to get rid of the space above and below the battery), and a couple of positioning tweaks to the Rectangles:-

```
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"
                 StretchDirection="Both">
            <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                    Width="400"
                    Height="100"
                    Background="Black">
                <Rectangle Width="180"
                           Height="100"
                           StrokeThickness="20"
                           Canvas.Top="0"
                           Stroke="White"
                           RadiusX="5"
                           RadiusY="5">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                             EndPoint="1,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="White"
                                          Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="White"
                                          Offset="{Binding Percent}" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                                          Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="40"
                           Height="50"
                           StrokeThickness="20"
                           Canvas.Top="25"
                           Canvas.Right="200"
                           Stroke="White"
                           RadiusX="5"
                           RadiusY="5" />

                <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill"
                         StretchDirection="Both"
                         Canvas.Left="200"
                         Height="100">
                    <TextBlock Text="1%"
                               Padding="0"
                               Margin="0"
                               LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                               LineHeight="20"
                               FontSize="20"
                               Foreground="White" />
                </Viewbox>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
```

Drop this into a window - you'll find that both the canvas and text scale in proportion to each other (and keep their aspect ratios) as the window is resized.

The battery doesn't completely align with the top and bottom of the text, but I suspect it's due to spacing present within the font itself. I found I could improve things by playing around with negative top and bottom margins on the `TextBlock`, but this is probably "hacky" as the amount of adjustment will depend on the font being used.

There are probably more elegant solutions, e.g. using a Geometry/Path for the battery icon instead. BTW have you seen the excellent "Metro Studio" tool? It's a free collection of XAML icons - there are a few batteries in there, and you might be able to adapt one to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer, and all the work you must have put into it. I appreciate it, but went with an approach based on the accepted answer. +1 from me.